# How to solve a coupled differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I tried different ways to solve this differential equation but I did not succeed. These is the first couple ODEs I try to solve. I hope somebody can give me a hint.

\begin{eqnarray}
\ddot{x} + ax - b\dot{y} = c
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
\ddot{y} + ay + b\dot{x} = 0
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the complex plane. Do "first" + i"second" equation and you'll get something elegant. Sum of equations with second multiplied by the imaginary unit:
$$(\ddot{x}+i\ddot{y})+a(x+iy)+b(-\dot{y}+i\dot{x})=c+0i$$
Use new complex variable $z=x+iy$:
$$\ddot{z}+a z +ib\dot{z}=c$$
This is a simple second order DE with known solutions. Even better, the particular solution is just $z=c/a$ and the homogenous part works out very elegantly with $z=Ce^{i\lambda t}$, which gets you to a completely real characteristic polynomials ($i$ multiplies out):
$$-\lambda^2-\lambda b+a=0$$
Of course, $\lambda$-s may still be a complex conjugate pair, but the fact that the polynomial is real simplifies everything.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not get your point. Can I simply put the first and second equation into $z$? Shall I solve my equations for $x$ and $y$? I do not understand where $\ddot{z} + az + ib\dot{z} = c$ comes from.

Comment: @Samuel. I combined two real functions $x$ and $y$ into one complex function $z=x+iy$. This is a special case that works here because the equations are really symmetric. Now just solve for complex $z$. The real part is $x$ and the imaginary part is $y$. And as a bonus, this gives you a really nice geometric representation of the solution as motion in the complex plane. I got the equation by adding together your two equations (and multiplied the second one by imaginary unit). Try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

$$x''+ax−by'=c \rightarrow (x''+ax−by'=c )'\rightarrow x'''+ax'-by''=0 \\y''+ay+bx'=0 \rightarrow x'=-\frac{y''+ay}{b} \rightarrow x''=-\frac{y'''+ay'}{b} $$ now put x',x'' into 1st equation 
you will have 
$$-\frac{y'''+ay'}{b}+ay-b\frac{y''+ay}{b}=0 $$